# PHP or others languages - understanding of isset() - when or not using it

Tags: php, isset

I have a little problem with the comprehension of isset(). In this example which comes from the book "Beginning PHP 5.3 - Wrox", I do not understand why the use of isset() does not work. Instead, the right way is simple to write:

if ($var1 or $var2) { // then your code}

and not: if ( isset($var1) or isset($var2) ) { // then your code}

---

If you need more details, please find the code below with which I have this small problem. Thank you for your help.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["submit"]) ) { storeInfos();}
elseif (isset($_GET["forget"]) ) { forgetInfos();}
else { display();}

function storeInfos() {

  if ( isset($_POST["firstname"]) ) { setcookie( "firstname", $_POST["firstname"], time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 365, "", "", false, true ); }

  if ( isset($_POST["city"]) )  { setcookie( "city", $_POST["city"], time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 365, "", "", false, true ); }

header( "Location: december6.php" );
};

function forgetInfos () {

if (isset($_COOKIE["firstname"]) ) { setcookie( "firstname", $_POST["firstname"], time() - 36000, "", "", false, true ); }

if (isset($_COOKIE["city"]) ) { setcookie( "city", $_POST["city"], time() - 36000, "", "", false, true ); }

header( "Location: december6.php" ); };

function display() {

$firstname = (isset($_COOKIE["firstname"]) ) ? $_COOKIE["firstname"] : "";
$city = (isset($_COOKIE["city"]) ) ? $_COOKIE["city"] : "";    }?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
<title>PHP example</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Welcome on my new website!</h1>

<?php 

if ( $firstname or $city ) // This line is my problem {

?> <p>Hello <?php echo $firstname ? $firstname : "Visitor" ?> of the town of <?php echo $city ? $city : "Unknown" ?> </p> 

<a href="december6.php?forget=forget">I would like to delete my personal information.</a>

<?php ; }

else { ?>
<form action="december6.php" method="post">

<label for="firstname">Votre prénom: </label> 
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="ex: Peter"/></br>
<label for="city">Votre domicile: </label> <input type="text" name="city" id="city" value="ex: Fribourg"/></br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="sumbit" value="Envoyer"/></br>

</form> <?php ; }
} ?>

</body> </html>
```

Comment: There are lots of isset(), which `isset` is not working, post only that code

Answer (score 3):

The code in an `if` branch will be evaluated, when the result of the condition expression is not "falsy". Falsy values are: `false`, `0`, `""`, `"0"`, `null`, `array()` (etc.). In a logical expression every base value will be evaluated to false if the value is falsy, and true if it is not falsy: result of `"0" && array()` is `false`, because `"0"` and `array()` are falsy:

`isset()` returns with `true` with falsy values also, except `null`. "Is set" means: the variable has no value (`null`), or it is not declared at all. Please, read the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php).

```
$a = "0";
$b = array();

if ($a && $b) {
    // will be skipped
}

if (isset($a) && isset($b)) {
    // will be executed
}
```

This is not true: <s>`isset($x)===((bool)($x))`</s>

Comment: I believe one should not call things like isset(""). Seems like wrong design.

Comment: Need for `isset()` is rare. With normal variables it has no sense. With arrays and objects `array_key_exists()` is more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> isset — Determine if a variable is set and is not **NULL**

If you want to check the value of something, then you do that without `isset`. If you want to check whether something exists, you need `isset`. For instance, let's suppose you have an instance of a `class` called `foo` and you want to refer to its `bar` method:

```
$foo->bar();
```

but it will yield an error if `$foo` does not exist, so you can check whether `$foo` exists before you call `bar`:

```
if (isset($foo)) {
    $foo->bar();
}
```